# Hide text of Android spinner

Tags: android

I have a spinner with a background image. But when I add array adapter to the spinner, the text is shown on the background image. I want to hide this text. There is also a TextView. My requirement is, when I click the image, the spinner should pop up and when I selects an item, the TextView gets updated with the selected item.

Comment: duplicate question but with no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342273/how-do-i-hide-the-text-on-a-spinner

Comment: I got across the same problem but i found my 9 patch png invalid and hence,fixing 9 patch and cleaning-building project worked for me. Can you please post your code so that it is easy for us to suggest you something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479579/remove-text-from-spinner - your solution

Answer (score 15):

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) d.findViewById(R.id.searchCriteria);  
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {  
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
// hide selection text  
((TextView)view).setText(null);  
// if you want you can change background here  
}  
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}  
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Create ghost_text.xml in your layouts folder with this text:

```
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Then use that file in your adapter like this:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> your_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        R.layout.ghost_text, your_list);
    your_spinner.setAdapter(your_adapter);
```

You should also be able to use this technique with other resource-based adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can define a xml-layout file, without any textview in it, and supply it to the adapter for the spinner.

e.g. empty_spinner_item.xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http..."
    android:layout_width=".." 
/>
```

and then use any adapter:

```
spinner.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.empty_spinner_item, ... ));
```

Comment: I have a spinner with a background image. But when I add array adapter to the spinner, the text is shown on the background image. I want to hide this text. There is also a TextView. My requirement is, when I click the image, the spinner should pop up and when I selects an item, the TextView gets updated with the selected item.

Comment: I can't hide the text of spinner. So I replace the spinner with a button. When button clicks, the spinner pop ups (spinner.performClick). I also wrote a OnItemSelectedListener to update the TextView with the selected item. But OnItemSelectedListener is not working :(. Any help please..

Comment: It works. StorageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
            View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
            {
 
             tv.setText(StorageSpinner.getSelectedItem()+"");
            }
 
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
        });

Comment: When I tried this, my app crashed with the error "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView."